# How to authenticate to flickr with Flickraw gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flickr

I want to upload a photo but need to authenticate with flickr in order to do so. I am using the flickraw gem but don't understand the instructions below:

```
require 'flickraw'

FlickRaw.api_key="... Your API key ..."
FlickRaw.shared_secret="... Your shared secret ..."

token = flickr.get_request_token(:perms => 'delete')
auth_url = token['oauth_authorize_url']

puts "Open this url in your process to complete the authication process : #{auth_url}"
puts "Copy here the number given when you complete the process."
verify = gets.strip

begin
  flickr.get_access_token(token['oauth_token'], token['oauth_token_secret'], verify)
  login = flickr.test.login
  puts "You are now authenticated as #{login.username}"
rescue FlickRaw::FailedResponse => e
  puts "Authentication failed : #{e.msg}"
end
```

Can someone explain to me what this code is doing and how I should use it.

Answer (score 1):

First , you should open http service

```
 rails server
```

On the Console , you will see

```
Open this url in your process to complete the authication process : http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx........
```

you have to copy the url and post it on your browser.

After log in , you will get a number , like

```
 xxx-xxx-xxx
```

just copy it onto your console!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new Flickr app. Get the api key and shared secret from there.
2. "flickr.get_request_token" creates a request oauth token from flickr. You might want to set permissions to :write if you want to upload instead of :delete
3. auth_url is where you have to redirect to. That url also contains the oauth request tokens that you just created.
4. Once you are in auth_url page ( for this you have to login to your Yahoo! account), you can  authorize your app to access your flickr account. This gives a verification id.
5. Use that verification id to you can get the oauth access tokens using this method call 'flickr.get_access_token'
6. Once you have the Oauth access tokens, you could do any api queries on flickr that your :perms would allow.

The entire process is described in detail here -  http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a pull request but here is an updated form of the documentation that should make this more clear

```
 == Simple

+#Place near the top of your controller i.e. underneath FlickrController < ApplicationController
  require 'flickraw'

+#Create an initializer file i.e. Flickr.rb and place it in config -> initializers folder
  FlickRaw.api_key="... Your API key ..."
  FlickRaw.shared_secret="... Your shared secret ..."

+#Examples of how the methods work
  list   = flickr.photos.getRecent

  id     = list[0].id
  ...
```